# If else condtional in ng-class?

Tags: angularjs

I have this part of code:

```
ng-class="{'gray':TicketDetail.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled==false || 'secondary-button': TicketDetail.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled==true}"
```

But problem is that this is not working.I dont get gray and remove secondary-button class if payoutenabled == false.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ternary operation :

```
 ng-class="TicketDetail.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled ? 'secondary-button' : 'gray'"
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
ng-class="{'gray': TicketDetail.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled===false, 'secondary-button': TicketDetail.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled===true}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just simplify your `ng-class`-expression to:

```
ng-class="{ 'gray': !TicketDetail.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled, 'secondary-button': TicketDetail.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled }"
```

as one of them can only be `true` if the other is `false` anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work :

```
ng-class="{'gray': !TicketDetail.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled , 'secondary-button': TicketDetail.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled}"
```

You don't need to add an `||` operator. You can just make a list of all the condition you need.
Moreover, you can also simplify your code, `==true` or `==false` isn't needed.